# initiating jobs in affectiva

Tags: json, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

I have a python script that I running on Ubuntu. I want to initiate a job in affectiva. I also need to save the json responses in mongodb. I am having trouble defining api (I tried Emotionapi, but I'd have to define emotionapi and don't know how) and figuring out how to save the json responses in mongodb. Below is my code. Please help. Thank you.

```
import affectiva
import requests
import json
import youtube_dl

username = 'xxx@xxxx.com'
passwd = 'xxxx'
r = requests.get('https://index.affectiva.com/', auth=(username, passwd))
response_data = r.json
response_text = r.text
print("response: %s" % str(response_data))
print("text: %s" % response_text)
api = ?(username,passwd)
# Upload a file for Processing
filename = 'https://youtu.be/zlg8QmkHPy0'
video = open(filename)
print("filename: %s" % filename)
job_url = api.create_job(filename)['self']


# Get face detection and emotion results
#job_status = api.query_job(job_url)['status']

if status == 'done':
    metrics_json = api.results(job_url)
print(metrics_json)

auth=(username,passwd)
headers={"Accept":"application/json"}

uri = 'https://index.affectiva.com/entries/8766564287617093404/representations/1867118/media'
#https://index.affectiva.com/jobs/1819405085186621725

print(requests.get(uri, auth=auth, headers=headers).json())
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: 1) How should I define api (api = ?(username,passwd). I tried Emotionapi, but I'd have to define emotionapi and don't know how   2) how to save the json responses in mongodb. thanks